# parsing config files in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, configuration

Actually I am devloping a php application and I came across a weird problem. 
I have a config file, myfile.ini. There is one category in it :

```
[MYFILES]
FILENAME=My file
FILEID=32404506123
FILEINFO=This file package now has no download limit giving you access to as much music, film and tv as you want.
```

My browser shows "cannot display the page" when I start extraxting anything from it. No matter it is MYFILES category or any other, like below:

```php
$fileconfig = get the path of myfile.ini;
$fileproperties= $this->_configreader->getParam ($fileconfig , 'FILEPROPERTIES', '' );
```

When I remove "no" from FILEINFO above, it works fine. Also when I put FILEINFO in doublequotes, working fine.

Please help me regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: What class is `_configreader` ?

Comment: This is my custom config reader. I am using parse_ini_file() to parse the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say what your problem is, as I can't find a question above.

I assume you have errors while using [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/function.parse-ini-file.php). PHP reads a very strict *.ini-format, thus most values needs to get enclosed by quotes.

> Note:  There are reserved words which must not be used as keys for ini files. These include: null, yes, no, true, false, on, off, none. Values null, no and false results in "", yes and true results in "1". Characters ?{}|&~![()^" must not be used anywhere in the key and have a special meaning in the value.
>
> *(From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/function.parse-ini-file.php))*

Comment: thanks mate. Actually i am new to php devlopment and just wondering why it's behaving like this. Thanks again.

Comment: @RiksAndroid An alternative would be to parse YAML-files. A lot of developers I know prefer YAML over the .ini-format these days and use the former one to store the application configuration. The downside here: The default PHP implementation "requires the LibYAML C library version 0.1.0 or higher to be installed"; see: http://php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php But there are also some pure PHP YAML classes out on the web…